# Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric

Tags: t-sql

How can I fix this error in T-SQL?  The following line executes successfully:

```
SET @dPERCENT_QC_COMPLETED = CASE WHEN @NUM_QC_RECEIVED = 0 
                               THEN 0 
                               ELSE @NUM_QC_COMPLETED / @NUM_QC_RECEIVED 
                             END
```

But this line fails with error code below:

```
SET @dPERCENT_QC_COMPLETED = CASE WHEN @NUM_QC_RECEIVED = 0
                               THEN 0
                               ELSE (100 * @NUM_QC_COMPLETED / @NUM_QC_RECEIVED)
                             END
```

Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 73
Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

@dPERCENT_QC_COMPLETED is a decimal(2).  The other variables are integers.  Problem I think is that currently these other integer values = 1, so this expression evaluates to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decimal(2)` is never going to able to cope with `100` percent complete. Why are you using that datatype?

Comment: Oh I didn't see that!  I forgot I multiply by 100.  You are right; this fixed it!